# Angular nested `ngFor` using variable from outer loop

Tags: angular, angular-ngfor

I am making a dynamic permissions list, how would I go about using the "item" from:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of PermissionsList.T1">
  <!-- Some code here -->
</div>
```

in a inner `ngFor` loop. I have tried the following, and other similar variations:

```html
<p *ngFor="let item2 of PermissionsList.{{item}}">test</p>
```

The `PermissionsList` example is like this:

```js
T1: Array [ "Business", "Recreation", "Vehicles" ]

Recreation: Array [ "Hunting", "Leisure" ]

Hunting: Array [ "Big_Game", "Bird", "Pest" ]

Big_Game: Array [ "Moose", "Elk" ]

​Pest: Array [ "Wild Boar", "Fox" ]

Bird: Array [ "Geese", "Sharp-tailed grouse" ]

​Leisure: Array [ "Hiking", "Bird Watching" ]

Business: Array [ "Trapping", "Utility", "Construction"]

Vehicles: Array [ "Half_ton", "ATV", "SnowMobile" ]
```

Comment: Use PermissionsList[item] instead of PermissionsList.{{item}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PermissionsList` is an `Array` of `Arrays` and you mean to iterate on the second arrays you can try this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let permission of PermissionsList">
  <div *ngFor="let item of permission ">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</div>
```

If `PermissionsList` is an `Object` of `Arrays` and you just want to display `T1` for example, try this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let t1 of PermissionsList['T1']">
  {{ t1 }}
</div>
```

Comment: Your'e Welcome ;)